# Block-less argdo on many files?

Tags: buffers, substitute

I am running a simple substitution on many files with `:argdo %s/foo/\rfoo/ge | update`. Vim shows the progress through files (number of substitutions in file) and when the screen fills up it blocks with the prompt:

```
...
"Data_357.csv" 63 lines, 22551 characters
"Data_358.csv" 204 lines, 946953 characters
-- More -- SPACE/d/j: screen/page/line down, b/u/k: up, q: quit
```

How can I make it run non-stop?

Comment: try `:silent! argdo %s/foo/\rfoo/ge | update` ... `silent` skips displaying normal messages and `!` skips error messages as well

Comment: Related to http://superuser.com/questions/430843/use-argdo-with-search-pattern-to-delete-line-while-suppressing-errors-and-requir

Comment: awesome! Thanks. So, will someone post an answer? (@spasic) I guess it's better to have this question on vi.stackexchange even though the superuser one is very similar...

Comment: @spasic you answered the question in a comment. Please move this to an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
:silent argdo %s/foo/\rfoo/ge | update
```

or

```
:silent! argdo %s/foo/\rfoo/g | update
```

- `silent` skips displaying normal messages
- `!` skips error messages as well

  - As per [this vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/using-argdo-to-change-multiple-files/), the `e` flag in substitute command can also be removed

For more options and in-built help, refer to [this Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/430843/use-argdo-with-search-pattern-to-delete-line-while-suppressing-errors-and-requir)